Azure Function App Pipeline Error for Key Vault - Parameter name cannot be empty
Getting the following error:
##[error]Error: Failed to update App service 'function-app-name' application settings. Error: BadRequest - Parameter name cannot be empty. (CODE: 400)

I'm following the docs found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-function-app-v2?view=azure-pipelines
Not sure why it's failing. Here is my task:
- task: AzureFunctionApp@2
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: functionAppLinux
              appName: $(functionAppName)
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              appSettings: |
                -AzureWebJobsStorage "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://$(keyVaultName).vault.azure.net/secrets/AzureWebJobsStorage)"
                -repeatorderstorage_STORAGE "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://$(keyVaultName).vault.azure.net/secrets/repeatorderstorage-STORAGE)"
                -AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://$(keyVaultName).vault.azure.net/secrets/AZURE-OPENAI-API-KEY)"
                -AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://$(keyVaultName).vault.azure.net/secrets/AZURE-OPENAI-ENDPOINT)"
                -AZURE_OPENAI_API_VERSION "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://$(keyVaultName).vault.azure.net/secrets/AZURE-OPENAI-API-VERSION)"


You need add blank space at the end of the each app setting line

Hi @Sean, Good day to you. At your convenience, please let us know if the either of the answers below to pass appSettings can resolve your issue in this post. Thx for your time and efforts.

To use multiline App settings key and value add a blank space at end of the each line.
for example:
appSettings: |
-key1 value1 
-key2 value2 
-key3 value3 

As you can see in the below screenshot there is a blank space after the key and value.

Below file worked for me
steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: functionAppLinux
              appName: $(functionAppName)
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              appSettings: |
                -AzureWebJobsStorage "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://$(keyVaultName).vault.azure.net/secrets/)" 
                -repeatorderstorage_STORAGE "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://$(keyVaultName).vault.azure.net/secrets/)" 
                -AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://$(keyVaultName).vault.azure.net/secrets/)" 
                -AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://$(keyVaultName).vault.azure.net/secrets/)" 
                -AZURE_OPENAI_API_VERSION "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://$(keyVaultName).vault.azure.net/secrets/)" 
                -Test Vivek 

OUTPUT:



I could reproduce the issue when deploying function app with multi-line app settings. From the logs, we could see the JSON context was not correctly converted.

The trick is to change the multi-line string indicator for appSettings from | to >
- task: AzureFunctionApp@2
  inputs:
    connectedServiceNameARM: '$(ARMSvcCnn)'
    appType: 'functionAppLinux'
    appName: '$(AzureFunctionApp)'
    package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/build$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    appSettings: >
      -TestEnvVar $(Build.BuildId)
      -CONNECTION_URL example$(Build.BuildId).com
      -AzureWebJobsStorage "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://$(keyVaultName).vault.azure.net/secrets/AzureWebJobsStorage)"
      -repeatorderstorage_STORAGE "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://$(keyVaultName).vault.azure.net/secrets/repeatorderstorage-STORAGE)"
      -AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://$(keyVaultName).vault.azure.net/secrets/AZURE-OPENAI-API-KEY)"
      -AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://$(keyVaultName).vault.azure.net/secrets/AZURE-OPENAI-ENDPOINT)"
      -AZURE_OPENAI_API_VERSION "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://$(keyVaultName).vault.azure.net/secrets/AZURE-OPENAI-API-VERSION)"
    deploymentMethod: 'runFromPackage'


In addition, please double check if you have to set the value for AzureWebJobsStorage with Key Vault secret, as it may incur the error below during deployment.


Thanks, I am getting the ##[error]Error: Unable to find the storage account associated with the function app. Any tips to resolve this? The storage account has firewall enabled.

As mentioned in my answer, that error was caused by your modification to the default value of AzureWebJobsStorage in app settings with an expression to retrieve secret value from Key Vault. That was also why I suggested in the answer, you double check if you have to set the value for AzureWebJobsStorage during the deployment. The default value was like DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<AccountName>;AccountKey=<AccountKey>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net. Please consider raising another post if the suggestion doesn't work for you.
